# Getting Selected Item from Action Bar spinner Navigation

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, spinner

I'm working on Action bar with spinner. I followed this tutorial 18th step [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

I want to get the selected item in the spinner box. I want to get the selected value using a `switch` `case` statement.
How can I get the selected item inside the `onOptionsItemSelected` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use the `onNavigationItemSelected` method to determine which item was selected from the spinner:

```
/**
 * Actionbar navigation item select listener
 * */
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

    SpinnerNavItem selectedItem = navSpinner.get(itemPosition);        

}
```

Comment: yeah its worked like a charm,before I tried to add in onOptionsItemSelected method,Now it works

Answer (score 0):

//Encontre la Siguiente Solución

```
private SpinnerAdapter adaptador;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.name_layout);

    spinnerFaena = getActionBar();
    spinnerFaena.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

   //Tengo Una Lista de Faenas que se Obtiene mediante WebService
   final List<String> faenas = listaFaenas();
            try {
               adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        name_layout.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        faenas);
}

  //En el metodo que captura el Listener
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int index, long arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(name_layout.this, "Estamos en " + adaptador.getItem(index).toString(),           
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Diego. You should be aware, though, that this site is English-only.